# Is it possible to implement Espresso as module to be part of the my Mavan automation project

Tags: android, maven, automation, android-espresso

I plan to upgrade old UIAutomator version solution to perform Android tests as a part of the my team's Maven automation project.
I was wondering if i can implement Espresso framework to be a module of my automation project?

In the Android testing training https://developer.android.com/training/testing/,
the guide explains and shows examples with the Android Studio and Gradle.

Is it possible to use Espresso not only in Android Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Espresso is a UI testing Library to test elements inflation of Android application. It has no dependency on Android Studio and can be use outside the AS IDE.

Comment: Does it comes with a server side apk solution or i need to integrate it with one?

Comment: You should be able to run service side emulators and use Espresso there as well. I integrate my tests, including espresso tests along with unit tests, and test them on virtual devices running on Mac, Linux and Windows platform on Github Actions and it works just fine. Also, you can use Espresso on Robolectric, so  that is another option for remote.

Comment: I was looking through android Espresso docs and didn't find data on how to configure the service when i create an emulator. From your experience can you direct me to such a guide or explain me what should i do ?

Comment: you dont need to configure Espresso. u can simply bundle up your test on your build server. Android emulator will take care of the rest.